# Apache 2 Fails to start after upgrade to PHP 5.3

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

I just upgraded to PHP 5.3 (Thread Safe VC6) on my windows server 2003 machine running Apache 2.2.4, and now Apache fails to start.

I tested the pre-packed development ini file, and Apache will start, but as soon as I start it with mysql.dll enabled it either fails, or gets stuck in the "starting" state in services.

I'll keep searching google for a solution, but any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I just thought I'd add that I've narrowed in a little bit on the problem, I was able to get the development ini to work by uncommenting the extensions directory value. Unfortunately my original ini still fails, so I suspect something in it needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Looks like it was a combination of both some old extensions that I needed to update, and I wasn't getting the errors messages since I was RDP'ing in, and didn't think to check the system or application logs.

I am still having an issue when I try to use error logs, however. The file is created fine, but it apparently bombs when it attempts to write to it.